# Yii2 Controller action is not receiving parameter

Tags: php, yii2

**Hello World!**

so here is the deal,developing a yii2 application for finding jobs and hiring people, so in the showjob action i am trying to pass the link in the controller like this

```
  /**
     * @param $link
     * @return string
     */
    public function actionShowjob($link)
    {


        $data['model'] = Job::find()->where(['link'=> $link ])->one();
        return $this->render('showjob',compact(['data']));
    }
```

where is the problem ? why it's not showing me that the page is not found?

Answer (score 0):

Ugh! everything is working i was trying to access the pages in the url like this

```
http://localhost/basic/web/site/job/jobshow/newjob
```

instead of

```
http://localhost/basic/web/job/showjob?link=newjob
```

Comment: if you define url rules in config file you can access pages using first url

Comment: please explain more sir or provide links to this subject i am trying to write rules but i am getting errors thanks @ParitoshMahale

Comment: all the details are [here](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/runtime-routing)